# How to bind List<Integer> values to selectManyListbox in JSF

Tags: jsf-2, glassfish, managed-bean

**The situation**:
I have a JavaServer Faces page and a session-scoped managed bean that has two `ArrayList<Integer>` properties: one for holding a list of possible values and another for holding a list of selected values. On the JSF page there is a `<h:selectManyListBox>` component with these two properties bound.

**The problem**: after submitting the form the selected values will be converted to string (the property of type ArrayList actually holds a couple of strings!); however, when I use a  converter, I get an error message like this:

> Validation Error: Value is not valid

**The question**: How can I bind an `ArrayList<Integer>` property to the `<h:selectManyListBox>` component properly?

Thank you for your kind helping me.

**The concrete codes**

The JSF page:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:selectManyListbox value="#{testBean.selection}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{testBean.list}"></f:selectItems>
            </h:selectManyListbox>
            <h:commandButton action="#{testBean.go}" value="go" />
            <ui:repeat value="#{testBean.selection}" var="i">
                #{i}: #{i.getClass()}
            </ui:repeat>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

And the managed bean:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

@javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean
@javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable
{
    private ArrayList<Integer> selection;
    private ArrayList<Integer> list;

    public ArrayList<Integer> getList()
    {
        if(list == null || list.isEmpty())
        {
            list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            list.add(1);
            list.add(2);
            list.add(3);
        }
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(ArrayList<Integer> list)
    {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> getSelection()
    {
        return selection;
    }

    public void setSelection(ArrayList<Integer> selection)
    {
        this.selection = selection;
    }

    public String go()
    {
            // This throws an exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
            /*for (Integer i : selection)
            {
                System.out.println(i);
            }*/
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The generic type information of `List<Integer>` is lost during runtime and therefore JSF/EL who sees only `List` is not able to identify that the generic type is `Integer` and assumes it to be default `String` (as that's the default type of the underlying `HttpServletRequest#getParameter()` call during apply request values phase).

You need *either* to explicitly specify a `Converter`, you can use JSF builtin [`IntegerConverter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/IntegerConverter.html):

```html
<h:selectManyListbox ... converter="javax.faces.Integer">
```

*or* just to use `Integer[]` instead, whose type information is clearly known during runtime:

```
private Integer[] selection;
```

Comment: Thank you! The code is working properly with the added IntegerConverter. I did not know about [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) until now...

Comment: @BalusC, thanks, this actually turned out to be the answer to my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14048382/516433).  This can be a painful one to figure out as it presents in strange ways.  However, I should have just known better...

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice pitfall one has to take care of! Just ran into the same problem with a `Set<Long>`- giving strange errors at runtime!

Comment: 1 day to figure out  about the `ClassCastException` issue arisen when using `List<Long>` object in `SelectManyMenu`. thanks alot @BalusC from saving of madness