# Java infering wrong type of a typed HashSet

Tags: java, jsf, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ClassCastException when calling TreeSet<Long>.contains( Long.valueOf( someLongValue ) )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048382/classcastexception-when-calling-treesetlong-contains-long-valueof-somelongva)

Please see the screenshot for the problem:

[image: Strange type inference problem]

It seems an entry in the Typed Set `cylinderIds` is suddenly of type `String` - but how did that happen?

The bean is used from within a JSF page, but I always thought that the type system in Java should prevent this ... Any idea what is going wrong here?

Using 1.7.0_06 64 Bit on Windows 7, the application is run within a JBoss 7.1.0 on the same Java version.

Comment: That code is just **broken** anyway, I'm not surprised of anything.

Comment: Those type checks happen only at compile-time and are optional. You need to find the place that populated the Set.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: harsh words. What is so broken here?

Comment: @Thilo: `while (cylinderIds.iterator().hasNext())`

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: Okay, that is rubbish.

Comment: At least he is able to use the debugging mode :)

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: that is just there because I got the exception when doing `for (Long cylinderId : cylinderIds)`, so I needed to explicitly create those lines. No worries there please ;-)

Comment: Well, maybe you actually added a `String` to the set. You *can* do that, if you override the generics somewhere else. `((Set)cylinderIds).add("Banana");` anywhere else in your code...

Comment: @Thilo: Thanks for the link, that did the trick! The problem is the loss of type information due to erasure at runtime within the JSF page. Using an explicit converter in the page and/or using a `Long[]` instead of the `Set<Long>` seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not exactly Java's fault. Generic type information is just lost during runtime. Java/JSF/EL does not run during compiletime, but during runtime. All it sees during runtime is a `Set`, not a `Set<Long>`.

When JSF sets submitted input values as bean properties, it retrieves them in first place as `String` as that's the default return type of `request.getParameter()`, which JSF is using under the covers to obtain request parameters. As long as no converter is specified, JSF will set those submitted `String` values unconverted in the `Set` via reflection. This is basically what is happening "under the covers":

```
package com.stackoverflow.q14521882;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Test {

    private Set<Long> set = new HashSet<Long>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Test test = new Test();
        Field field = test.getClass().getDeclaredField("set");
        Object object = field.get(test);
        if (object instanceof Collection) {
            ((Collection) object).add("string");
        }
        System.out.println(test.set.iterator().next().getClass()); // CCE!
    }

}
```

It would work when you was using `Long[]` instead of `Set<Long>`, but given that it's a `Set` in first place, you'd like to hold unique values only and the `Long[]` is therefore likely not an option. In order to solve it, you need to explicitly specify a `Converter` in the input component. You can use JSF builtin [`LongConverter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/LongConverter.html) for this, which has a converter ID of [`javax.faces.Long`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/constant-values.html#javax.faces.convert.LongConverter.CONVERTER_ID):

```html
<h:selectManyListbox ... converter="javax.faces.Long">
```

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that you ask for a new `Iterator` each time you step into the `while`. The second problem is that `Iterator` is generic so you better do something like this:

```
Iterator<Long> cylinderIter = cylinderIds.iterator();

while(cylinderIter.hasNext()) {
    cylinderIter.next() // ...
    // do something
}
```

The third problem is that I can't see where you happen to populate that `Set`. I can help you more if you show us the code.

Comment: I know about the `Iterator` logic, it just came there for my debugging. Since it is/was not working anyway, I didn't care about the iterator being constructed over and over again :-)

Answer (score 0):

Without to see your code I could answering that something is changing the type of your set:

> Generics are implemented by type erasure: generic type information is
>   present only at compile time, after which it is erased by the
>   compiler. The main advantage of this approach is that it provides
>   total interoperability between generic code and legacy code that uses
>   non-parameterized types (which are technically known as raw types).
>   **The main disadvantages are that parameter type information is not available at run time, and that automatically generated casts may fail
>   when interoperating with ill-behaved legacy code.** There is, however,
>   a way to achieve guaranteed run-time type safety for generic
>   collections even when interoperating with ill-behaved legacy code.

The [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/generics.html) article of oracle documentation explain you better.

Try this code for see when the problem is happening:

```
Set<Long> s = Collections.checkedSet(new HashSet<Long>(), Long.class);
```

Comment: I think it is because of concurrency maybe.

Comment: That code - which I originally had - threw a `ClassCastException`, so for debugging purposes I changed the code. I know that it won't work the way it's seen on the screenshot, but the actual problem is not my iteration but the type.

Comment: Could you add the code where you populate the Set? Perphaps you are changing your set (cylinderIds) using something like this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html#diamond and your type is changing; althought, I couldn't imaging how without to see more code.

Comment: @jenaiz please vote to close this question as exact duplicate of the question mentionend by Thilo

Comment: Yes, that gives me the clue to investigate. But the answer in the other post don't have a reference to the documentation, and I want to be sure that was right ;)