# ClassCastException in selectManyMenu - Integer cannot be cast to String

Tags: jsf, primefaces, converters

The list passed to the select's value is of Integer type.

```
<p:selectManyMenu id="estabelecimentos" value="#{questionarioMB.estabelecimentosIds}" var="e" converter="#{estabelecimentoConverter}" style="width:100%" filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains" showCheckbox="true">
    <f:selectItems value="#{questionarioMB.estabelecimentos}" var="estabelecimento" itemValue="#{estabelecimento}" itemLabel="#{estabelecimento.nomefantasia}" />
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{estabelecimentoMB.getIdentificadorByEstabelecimentoId(e.id)}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{e.nomefantasia}" />
    </p:column>
</p:selectManyMenu>
```

Netbeans cannot find the attributes in the outputTexts ("unknown property") and the line throwing the exception is the following:

```
this.estabelecimentosIds.parallelStream().forEach((Integer id) -> {
    this.questionarioBean.insertQuestionarioHasEstabelecimento(this.questionarioBean.getLastId() + 1, id);
});
```

The converter:

```
@Named
public class EstabelecimentoConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, String value) {
        if (value != null && value.trim().length() > 0) {
            try {
                EstabelecimentoMB estabelecimentoMB = (EstabelecimentoMB) fc.getExternalContext().getApplicationMap().get("estabelecimentoMB");
                return estabelecimentoMB.getEstabelecimentos().get(Integer.parseInt(value));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Erro de Conversão", "Estabelecimento inválido."));
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object o) {
        if (o != null) {
            return String.valueOf(((Estabelecimento) o).getId());
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

P.S.: I can't use the field `tradingName` because it can be repeated in table `establishment`, so I must use the "id" to differentiate them. The first column has the identifier for that establishment (in another table, "client_has_establishment", and can be repeated as well - but not for the same `client_id`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on BalusC's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13866179/1639141

Changed the converter to JSF builtin [IntegerConverter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/IntegerConverter.html):

`<p:selectManyMenu ... converter="javax.faces.Integer">`